# How to pass path parameters to JSON used for AWS Lambda Invocation?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, rest, aws-lambda

I'm trying to invoke AWS Lambda via Java to call my REST API using a JSON file. The JSON file looks like this:

```
{
  "httpMethod": "PUT",
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json"
  },
  "path": "/some-api/v1/channels/company/employees/{id}",
  "pathParameters": {
    "id": "%s"
  },
  "body" : "{\"name\": \"Jeff\", \"language\": \"en-US\", \"job\": {\"location\": \"NYC\", \"jobCode\": \"0000\"}}",
  "isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

The `{id}` in the path is supposed to get replaced with the id that is in the `pathParameters`. I can see the id in `pathParameters` gets replaced when AWS Lambda is invoked but not the `{id}` in the actual path. This throws an illegal character argument exception as the `{}` are not being filled when calling my API. What do I have to change here?

NOTE: I am NOT using API Gateway so please don't suggest mapping or anything I have to do in the UI unless it can be done in the JSON itsef...

Comment: Not much information to go on here. You appear to reading the JSON from file and sending it, presumably as the payload in InvokeRequest, when invoking the Lambda function. How are you populating the payload from the JSON? Where is your code that make the parameter substitution for `id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `pathParameters` only responds to the `resource` tag. I fixed this by adding `%s` to the end of the path. :

```
{
  "httpMethod": "PUT",
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json"
  },
  "path": "/some-api/v1/channels/company/employees/%s",
  "body" : "{\"name\": \"Jeff\", \"language\": \"en-US\", \"job\": {\"location\": \"NYC\", \"jobCode\": \"0000\"}}",
  "isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

Thanks for your shitty documentation, AWS.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still looking for this information, you can also add `pathParameters` to you JSON:

```json
{
    ...
    "pathParameters": {
        "id": 123
    }   
}
```

This is directly taken from the lambda, without the need to explicitly set the `resource` or `path` values if you have using the `pathParameters` function from the SDK.